# Zend Framework 2 - How modular should an application be structured?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, module, zend-framework2

I am in the process of learning the Zend Framework 2. Although everything is still really new for me, I want to try how far I get with writing a small gallery application.

The application consists of a user login, an admin login, a browser uploader, some gallery editing functions and of course a view where the selected gallery's images can be viewed.

I've already laid out the url structure and the needed views, but I am unsure how I should structure the application.

To my understanding, the Zend Framework 2 is all about the modules, that means independent chunks of code that can be used together to build a larger application. Thats why I am thinking of splitting the application into 2 different modules (I know I can probably use already existing modules for this): Authentication and gallery, which also includes the uploader.

On the other hand, I could split it in three modules: Authentication, gallery and separate uploader. If the gallery would be written in a way that you can also specify a path to a directory on a server that holds images (of course that path could also be found in the database), that could make sense, because that way the browser uploader would be just a way to deliver the images.

Is there any recommended way on how modular an application should be structured in Zend Framework 2? Is my proposed 3 module structure already too modular – maybe small applications like this should be written as one module?

Comment: My current project, at 50% complete has over 100 modules. However, the number is irrelevant; the more you 'do' the more you need. Modules need to be **specific to the what they do** and to **do that thing only** for the greatest flexibility and reuse-ability. Consider your uploading, would it be possible to reuse 'upload' functionality?

Comment: @AlexP Yes I would write the module in a way it can be reused. So you would say it is wise to go as modular as possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [ZfcUser](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser) module and see how extensible ZF2 module can be created. If you look at modules wiki you can see examples how ZfcUser can be extended by using EventManager. Also you can read great post [Some tips to write better Zend Framework 2 modules](http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/2013/01/21/some-tips-to-write-better-zend-framework-2-modules/) that will help you to understand modules concept better.